# Can we calculate the range form mean and standard deviation in a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

Suppose in a normal distribution the mean is 90 and the standard deviation is 10. Then what is the range?
Would the following be an acceptable way to find the range, where $\sigma$ represents the standard deviation and $\mu$ represents the mean? $$\text{Range} = \mu + 3 \sigma - \mu + 3 \sigma = 6 \sigma$$

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: The range of a normal distribution is $\infty$.  Not everything is within three standard deviations!

Answer (score 1):

Standard deviation and mean give a probability mass distribution, which is continuous. That means that you can't talk about discrete things (like saying "there are exactly $x$ elements greater than some cutoff $n$) just on the basis of mean and standard deviation. As such, you can't say with certainty that "there are no elements less than the lower bound $a$ or greater than the upper bound $b$", so you can't give discrete values to the bound $[a,b]$ over which your range would be defined.

What the mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution *does* let you do is make claims about the relative probability of an element existing at any spot along the distribution, so you could pick some set cutoff deviation (say, perhaps $3 \sigma$) and say that $99.7\%$ of the probability mass lies within a $\pm3\sigma$ bound.